# Нужен динамический запрос MS SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос, cursor

Помогите пожалуйста! Есть 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE Options (
    id_opt smallint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [name_opt] varchar(10)
    );    
CREATE TABLE Items (
    id_item int NOT NULL,
    id_opt smallint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Options(id_opt),
    some_date smalldatetime,
    [some_val] int
    );
```

Надо построить таблицу вида

```
----------name0   Name1 …   nameN
id_item0    Value   Value   …   Value
id_item1    Value   Value   …   Value
```

Заполнение данными:

```
INSERT INTO params VALUES (1, 'param_1');
INSERT INTO Options VALUES (2, 'param_2');
INSERT INTO Options VALUES (3, 'param_3');
INSERT INTO Options VALUES (4, 'param_4');
INSERT INTO Options VALUES (5, 'param_5');

INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1, 1, '1980-11-1 11:15:10', 5);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1, 1, '1980-9-1 11:15:20', 15);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1, 1, '1981-8-5 11:15:30', 234);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1, 1, '1980-10-1 11:15:40', 654);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1, 2, '1980-10-1 11:15:10', 7);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1, 3, '1980-10-1 11:15:10', 854);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (2, 1, '1980-10-1 11:15:10', 75);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (2, 3, '1980-10-1 11:15:10', 84);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (2, 5, '1980-10-1 11:15:10', 33);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (3, 1, '1980-10-1 11:15:10', 35);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (3, 2, '1980-10-1 11:15:10', 22);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (3, 3, '1980-10-1 11:15:10', 15);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (3, 4, '1980-10-1 11:15:10', 45);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (3, 5, '1980-10-1 11:15:10', 564);
```

Я написал:

```
SELECT id_item,
       param_1 = ISNULL((SELECT [some_val] FROM Items WHERE [name_opt] = 'param_1' AND id_item =
  sel.id_item AND some_date = '1980-10-1 11:15:10'),0),
       param_2 = ISNULL((SELECT [some_val] FROM Items WHERE [name_opt] = 'param_2' AND id_item =
  sel.id_item AND some_date = '1980-10-1 11:15:10'),0),
       param_3 = ISNULL((SELECT [some_val] FROM Items WHERE [name_opt] = 'param_3' AND id_item =
  sel.id_item AND some_date = '1980-10-1 11:15:10'),0),
       param_4= ISNULL((SELECT [some_val] FROM Items WHERE [name_opt] = 'param_4' AND id_item =
  sel.id_item AND some_date = '1980-10-1 11:15:10'),0),
       param_5= ISNULL((SELECT [some_val] FROM Items WHERE [name_opt] = 'param_5' AND id_item =
  sel.id_item AND some_date = '1980-10-1 11:15:10'),0)
     FROM (select id_item, [name_opt], [some_val] from Items join Options
ON (Items.id_opt = Options.id_opt)) sel
     GROUP BY id_itemt
```

Выдает верный результат, но это не динамическая структура, если добавится новая опция в Options, надо будет дописывать "param_6=...". Динамику можно сделать через курсор, только я не понимаю как. Во внутренних селектах, где "some_date = '1980-10-1 11:15:10'", это временная реализация, надо будет это организовать в функцию с аргументом date, чтобы по дате выдавал ту самую таблицу. Но мне пока хотя бы просто построить динамический запрос, который я не могу написать.

Comment: Вопрос решил, спасибо за внимание

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.